# JQuery Masonry + InfiniteScroll: Overlapping issue after newly fetched items

Tags: jquery, overlapping

The title pretty much says it. I have a masonry image layout and want to dynamically load news contents with InfiniteScroll. Buch the new items get positioned in the top left corner again.

Link: http://thomasmaier.me/2g12b/

It's a Wordpress installation and InfiniteScroll is a plugin while Masonry is hardcoded.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

<script>


  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#content');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post'
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.navigation',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '.navigation .alignleft a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.post'
      },
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, isAnimatedFromBottom ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });


</script>
```

I tried everything I could, searched here, looked at the Help section here http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html but it doesn't work.

Can you help me out?

Comment: I can't see, where you are loading new posts (= images).

Comment: What do you mean? Code-side or in the browser? Here is a screenshot: http://cl.ly/Io4x - You scroll to the page bottom and they load. But they are behind the already loaded images.

Comment: I just found out why: The infinitescroll.js is never loaded, so `$container.infinitescroll` errors out.

Comment: It loads all the time, it's just not in this code here because it's a Wordpress Plugin which adds the script itself. InfiniteScroll works as I said and as you can see on the live site. The positioning is just wrong and it seems that the Masonry thing doesn't work anymore for the second fetch, so it just displays everything in one row with positioning in the top left corner.

Comment: No, I actually meant it is not loaded on the page behind the link, you provided: http://imgur.com/a/jV31p

Comment: Oh, okay. How can I fix that? The JS is obviously loading somehow, otherwise the second page's items wouldn't load at all...

Comment: **Resolved.** The plugin didn't work right, so I included the JS by hand. Also I changed what is in the code sample "isAnimatedFromBottom" to "true".

Comment: So.. the whole issue is resolved?